# Why is my symlink not working?

Tags: cfour

I am attempting to complete calculations for atoms using CFOUR.
I cloned a GitHub repository that included a correct GENBAS file.
I then created a folder outside of the directory of the git clone to complete the calculations.
In this folder, I added a correct ZMAT input, a correct script to run the CFOUR calculation, and, most importantly, a symbolic link to the GENBAS file in the git clone directory.

The calculation did not yield a working output.
I attempted to change the ZMAT input, as I wondered whether that was the source of the  issue.
I also tested different scripts to run the calculations.
An output was generated in all these cases however it never included a calculation as it couldn’t detect a basis-set in a GENBAS file.

I only resolved the problem by copying the GENBAS file directly into the directory where I was running the calculations (and removing the symlink).

Are symlinks therefore not compatible with CFOUR calculations?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to show what you tried, and what the result was.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.